# Calculate number of minutes between configurable hours

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have a `Journey` object that has a `DateTime JourneyStartTime { get; set; }` and a `DateTime JourneyEndTime { get; set; }`. I want to calculate the total number of minutes that the journey spent between 10pm and 6am (note this goes over midnight).

I have tried using TimeSpans for indicating the 10pm and 6am, but I am not sure if that is the best data type to use.

The domain for this logic is insurance based. Company X wants to score drivers that drive between X - Y hours. Those hours ought to be configurable. Here's a scenario:

> A journey takes place on the same day between 5pm and 6pm. Company X Inurance is interested in journeys between 10pm and 6am. How many minutes did that journey spend in the time period that Company X is interested in?

The answer to the above is: 0, but my code is giving 60 minutes (here is a [dotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tdgCbD)).

Here is the code.

**CODE**

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var shortSameDayJourney = new Journey {
            JourneyId = 1,
            // start of journey - 5pm - start
            JourneyStartTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 17, 17, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            // end of journey - 6pm - end
            JourneyEndTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 17, 18, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc)
        };

        var scoreTimePeriod = new InsurerTimePeriodScoreSetting {
            // start of insurer's time period.
            StartOfTimePeriod = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromHours(22),
            // end of insurer's time period.
            EndOfTimePeriod = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromHours(30)     
        };

        var minutesInTimePeriod = getNumberOfMinutesThatJourneyWasInTimePeriod(shortSameDayJourney, scoreTimePeriod);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of minutes the journey was within the time period the insurer had sepcified:");       
        Console.WriteLine(minutesInTimePeriod + " minutes");
    }

    public static double getNumberOfMinutesThatJourneyWasInTimePeriod(
        Journey journey,
        InsurerTimePeriodScoreSetting insurerTimePeriod) {

        var JourneyStart = journey.JourneyStartTime;
        var JourneyEnd = journey.JourneyEndTime;

        var timeSpan = insurerTimePeriod.EndOfTimePeriod - insurerTimePeriod.StartOfTimePeriod;
        var startDif = (JourneyStart - insurerTimePeriod.StartOfTimePeriod);
        var endDif =  (insurerTimePeriod.EndOfTimePeriod - JourneyEnd);

        var time = timeSpan - startDif - endDif;

        return time.TotalMinutes;
    }
}

public class Journey {
    public int JourneyId {get;set;}
    // journey start date and time in UTC, comes form a tracking device on vehicle.
    public DateTime JourneyStartTime {get;set;}
    // journey end date and time in UTC, comes form a tracking device on vehicle.
    public DateTime JourneyEndTime {get;set;}
}

public class InsurerTimePeriodScoreSetting {
    public DateTime StartOfTimePeriod {get;set;}
    public DateTime EndOfTimePeriod {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timespan only gives your raw time between 2 `DateTime's`
 so i had to changed your `Journey` initialization so i will be able to compare on the same day

```
   var shortSameDayJourney = new Journey
   {
       JourneyId = 1,
       // start of journey - 5pm - start
       JourneyStartTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 17, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc),
       // end of journey - 6pm - end
       JourneyEndTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 18, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    };
```

same for  `InsurerTimePeriodScoreSetting`

```
 var scoreTimePeriod = new InsurerTimePeriodScoreSetting
 {
     // start of insurer's time period. 18/12 22:00
      StartOfTimePeriod = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 22, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),   // DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromHours(22),
     // end of insurer's time period. 19/12 6:00
     EndOfTimePeriod = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day + 1, 6, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)  // DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromHours(30)
 };
```

now all you need to do is a simple check - if Journey time is between `InsurerTimePeriodScoreSetting`

```
if (JourneyStart >= insurerTimePeriod.StartOfTimePeriod && JourneyEnd <= insurerTimePeriod.EndOfTimePeriod)
{
// your same calculation here
}
else
   return 0;
```

Comment: Hmm how is `EndOfTimePeriod = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day + 1, 6, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)` configurable? If the compnany decides that the period it is interested in is **6am** to **9am** your code won't work then?

Comment: @J86: Stackoverflow is not a programming service ;-) styx's code should get you going and you have issues making it configurable, you can post a new question.